# Indexing PostGIS table by tile boundaries

Tags: postgis, tiles, mapnik, extents, spatial-index

I have a PostGIS table with 2M rows, all Points. I'm creating tiles from the data, but it's quite slow.

Although I have the normal geometry indexes enabled on the table, I wonder if it's possible to index better according to tile boundaries (which are alwayws the same).

Or is the normal `geom_idx` taking care of this already?

Comment: did you cluster on the geom_idx?

Comment: No, I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact possible. And it may even cluster a little better (especially for polygons). I recommend using a quadtile key/quadkey/quadtree system to refer to the item's tile. See http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/ for some visualization, well documented code, and explanation of different ways to refer to and calculate a tile.